# RxJavaPlugins.getInstance is deprecated

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I override my schedulers for testing with:

```
RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook(object : RxJavaSchedulersHook() {
    override fun getIOScheduler() = Schedulers.immediate()
    override fun getComputationScheduler() = Schedulers.immediate()
    override fun getNewThreadScheduler() = Schedulers.immediate()

  })
```

But docs says:

> Deprecated use the static methods of RxJavaHooks.

How can I override those schedulers using `RxJavaHooks` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Release notes for 1.1.7](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/releases) contain code samples how to do that in java. Small excerpt for setting computation scheduler:

```
RxJavaHooks.setOnIOScheduler(current -> Schedulers.immediate())
RxJavaHooks.setOnComputationScheduler(current -> Schedulers.immediate())
RxJavaHooks.setOnNewThreadScheduler(current -> Schedulers.immediate())
```

There is also

> By default, all RxJavaHooks delegate to the original RxJavaPlugins
>   callbacks so if you have hooks the old way, they still work.
>   `RxJavaHooks.reset()` resets to this delegation and `RxJavaHooks.clear()`
>   clears all hooks (i.e., everything becomes a pass-through hook).

Comment: Small comment: in Java each expression should be finished with `;` symbol